# Joining raster layer and vector (points) in ArcGIS 10

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, vector, attribute-joins, spatial-join

I have a raster layer (land cover) and a vector point layer, and I want to calculate the value of each point in terms of the type of land cover so that it is added to the attribute table. I tried to convert the raster to vector so that I could use the intersect tool or perform a spatial join, but the raster layer is too large (over 2MB) so the conversion failed. I also tried splitting the raster so that it was broken into smaller tiles, but the processing time was taking forever. Does anyone know an alternative way to do this?

Comment: You want the Extract Values to Points tool, the question I just marked this as a duplicate of has more information on that as well as several non-ArcGIS options.

Comment: Thanks @DanC - much appreciated. Sadly I don't have a license for spatial analyst so I ended up manually checking the points by selecting by attributes and checking their position on the raster (I had less points than I thought in the end so it didn't take as long as expected). Cheers